# How do I store accented characters in S3 metadata?

Tags: java, scala, utf-8, amazon-s3

I am trying to store accented characters such as `ò` in the metadata of an S3 object.  I am using the REST API which according to this page only accepts US-ASCII:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Is there a way to convert Strings in Scala or Java from `Bòrd` to `B\u00F2rd`?

I have tried using `Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD)` but the character when submitted to S3 is still causing an error because it appears as `ò`.  When I try to print out the returned String it is also showing `ò`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normalized unicode string is just normalized in terms of composing characters, not necessarily to ASCII. Using `NFKC` would be more likely to convert characters to ASCII forms, but certainly would not reliably to do so.

It sounds like what you want is to *escape* non-ascii characters. You could use e.g. [UnicodeEscaper](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/translate/UnicodeEscaper.html) from commons-lang, and [UnicodeUnescaper](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/translate/UnicodeUnescaper.html) to translate back.

Comment: I didn't go with UnicodeEscaper and UnicodeUnescaper, although yours is marked as the correct answer because it does work and gave me inspiration.

I wrote my own escaper and unescaper which can be seen at:  https://gist.github.com/aembleton/c3495438eac9ea19fff6